Attitudes to man-made famine in WW1
Have any western governments condemned the use of famine as a weapon of war in World War 1 (or acknowledged their culpability)? Have there been attempts to prosecute the responsible for the genocide?

The Blockade of Germany, or the Blockade of Europe, occurred from 1914 to 1919. The prolonged naval blockade was conducted by the Allies during and after World War I[3] in an effort to restrict the maritime supply of goods to the Central Powers, which included Germany, Austria-Hungary, and the Ottoman Empire. The blockade is considered one of the key elements in the eventual Allied victory in the war. In December 1918, the German Board of Public Health claimed that 763,000 German civilians had already died from starvation and disease caused by the blockade. An academic study done in 1928 put the death toll at 424,000.1 An additional 100,000 people may have died during the post-armistice continuation of the blockade in 1919.


Perfectly good question, and answers could be found in printed media. Start with Churchill, he wasn't too shy about his views. Then look for anyone opposed to his speeches.

Should note that views on the subject were colored by western views on race at the time (even though late 19th century science already debunked the theoretical foundations of Victorian racialism, via long term studies of separated twins and adopted siblings). Starving Irish or Indians, or even gassing the latter, was openly contemplated by some policymakers. Suffering of German civilians, on the other hand, elicited some concern, as the upper class English of the time felt a kinship there, outside of the war.

I’m voting to close this question because World War I finished in 1918, so this is a historical matter.  The "prosecute the culpable" is a bit daft, since everybody's dead.

@JamesK the US Congress seems to hold a different opinion: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_recognition_of_the_Armenian_genocide#:~:text=The%20United%20States%20recognizes%20the,Congress%2C%20and%20by%20presidential%20announcement

I don't see the relevance of that at all.  WW1 ended in 1918.  Questions of "what happened in 1918?" are relevant to history and only indirectly relevant to politics now.  For example if there is an active movement calling for prosecution of Lloyd George, please indicate.  Otherwise this is an off topic question about a historical war.

Not between the wars. In fact, the UK & France pushed for that to be expressly legal then, although the US disagreed (at least under Hoover). Later on, IDK, but then there were then many other things potentially to apologize for, mass bombing of cities etc. (Of course, the Nazis did that too.) Most of the current enhanced humanitarian bend of GC came after WW2 as the Soviets found convenient to push for it, somewhat surprisingly, perhaps, allying themself in that regard with the 'bleeding hearts' from the West.

attempts to prosecute the responsible for the genocide?

Definitely not. It wasn't overtly illegal then either. Even the Nazis got away 'scot free' for starving Leningrad. No charges at Nuremberg on that. Or for the 'Hunger Plan' as such. (See my H.SE answer which details that with quotes from sources.)

It would probably clarify things if you mention when it became illegal.  It was 1949 protocols of the Geneva Conventions,  specifically in response to WWII practices.

I think it is a mistake to view the situation in 1918 through the lens of the genocide convention, let alone call it man-made.
A century ago, food supplies were generally much more precarious than they are in the Western world today. Bad weather, flooding, a bad harvest could severely impact the food supply of a region. By 1910, German agriculture was partly modernized, requiring an import of nitrate fertilizer -- which also happens to be a major ingredient in explosives. It was also partly not modernized, relying manpower and draft horses which were also required at the front. In 1918, Germany and Austria-Hungary were controlling much of Ukraine and what is now Poland and Belarus, then part of Russia. They did not manage to grow and harvest food because too many of their resources were fighting on the Western Front.
Regarding international law at the time, read about

blockade as an act of war,
commerce raiding, prize law, and contraband, and the precedents set during and after the American Civil War.


Have there been attempts to prosecute the responsible for the genocide?

In the middle ages, they disinterred a pope and put the corpse on trial. That has since gone out of fashion.

Indeed, but a British Labour gov't offered a half-apology for the Irish potato famine. https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/jul/20/tony-blairs-apology-for-irish-famine-written-by-aides-papers-reveal I'm just saying there are intermediate steps to disinterring someone.

The US Congress recognized the Armenian genocide in 2019 - although most arguments about the genocide conventions etc. apply here as well.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad: it's far easier to do that when you're not the one blamed [for it]. And Turkey is almost always in a half-way house wrt to EUrope and even NATO (see F-35 cancellation etc.) So [the US] blaming Turkey is surely easier than blaming the UK for anything.
